# Java Unable to add a new list item

Tags: java, list

I am generating a list from the Registery using the code below.

```
  List<String> options = Arrays.asList(Advapi32Util.registryGetStringArray(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key, value)
```

Later on in the code I want to add to this list However the add method is not working.

The following code below give me an java.lang.unsupportedOperationException.

```
  options.add("Test");


  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
```

Any ideas.

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.asList()` returns an immutable list. Instead `new ArrayList<>()` could be used. The code would then look like follows:

```java
List<String> options = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
    Advapi32Util.registryGetStringArray(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key, value)));
options.add("Test");
```

Comment: Thanks let me give that a try.

Comment: Java doesn't seem to link that. The method add(String) in the type List<String> is not applicable for the arguments (String[]).  Is it becuase I am getting it from the reg?

Comment: I overlooked that the method returns an array. As you can pass collections to the `ArrayList` constructor the only change in your code would be wrapping it with `new ArrayList<>()`. See answer update.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.asList creates immutable list which cannot be modified.